# What would be the best way to consume SOAP XML web services on YII2?

Tags: php, xml, soap, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to consume a (Microsoft)SOAP XML Web Service provided by my client.
I am already trying with [**`mongosoft/yii2-soap-client`**](https://github.com/mohorev/yii2-soap-client) and have some success.

But the main problem is that I always end with a string that I cant parse JSON or an object.There must be an easier o more trustable way to consume a service like this.

This is an example of what I am using to consume it.

```
'clientApi' => [
    'class' => 'mongosoft\soapclient\Client',
    'url' => 'https://*****.ngrok.io/WSIConsult/WSIConsult.asmx?WSDL', 
    'options' => [
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    ],
]
```

and

```
public function getStates()
{
    $client = Yii::$app->clientApi;
    $stRs =  $client->consult_states();
    $xml_string = $stRs->Consult_StatesResult->any;
    $string = '<?xml version="1.0"?><rs>'.$xml_string.'</rs>'; //I tried this
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string );
    $json  = json_encode($xml);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    return $data;
}
```

Here a capture of Xdebug stopped before the return.

[image: Xdebug info]

some names may change because I translated variables.

Comment: Remember, just because you are using a framework does not remove the ability to do it all in vanilla PHP. Frameworks sit on top of PHP they do not remove or replace it

Comment: Yup, I am reading and trying to understand soapclient. Looks very complicated. About the page you shared, its Yii1.

Comment: When you call `$stRs =  $client->consult_states();` the `$stRs` should be an object, isn't it? Can you include a print_r() of that variable also use a '<pre>' tag for better formatting.

Comment: Yes it is an object I will add the Xdebug capture just give me a sec.

Comment: I recommend that you use standard SoapClient and wsdl2phphenerator that will generate the necessary classes for you from the WSDL. That way you will receive structured objects instead of a string. Keep in mind that object mapping and such has to be done in the classmap array that you pass to SoapClient.

Comment: so long for the over-clever @RiggsFolly :D

Comment: If your SOAP client makes you work with XML, then you're using the wrong SOAP client. Try PHP's `SoapClient`, like others are suggesting.